# Как вставить одиночный JavaScript в редакторе Wordpress для поста и страницы?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, header, hook

Трубуется в Wordpress (у меня версия 3.6) простыми действиями, желательно из редактора поста, подключить одну функцию JavaScript для одной страницы.

Просьба, поделитесь опытом.

Comment: В результате я воспользовался плагином  Allow Javascript in Posts and Pages https://wordpress.org/plugins/allow-javascript-in-posts-and-pages/

Comment: Сыроват и без поддержки, намаешься.

Answer (score 7):

В редакторе поста **в текстовом режиме** возможна вставка тегов `script` "как есть". То есть просто вставляете свой код в поле редактирования поста:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function funcName(){...}
</script>
```

либо

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ссылка_на_файл_с_функцией"></script>
```

Comment: Не сработает, потому как в head надо вставлять.

Comment: @VasilyukDmitry матчасть: "JavaScript can be placed in the <body> and the <head> sections of an HTML page." http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp

Comment: Тут вопрос не в можно, а как технически грамотно. Грамотно вообще в footer и header. Тут вопрос оптимизации загрузки стоит. Вставлять скрипт в файл вообще технически неграмотно. Потом есть особенности worpress

Comment: Ваш предыдущий комментарий ставил вопрос как раз о можно или нельзя. Ответ: можно. Не обладая информацией о наличии у пользователя доступа к файлам исходников темы и желания в них ковыряться, техническую целесообразность обсуждать довольно сложно

Comment: http://seoweb.in.ua/2011/12/wordpress-y-javascript/

Comment: Насколько мне известно, до версии 3 нельзя было вставить JS в редакторе.

Comment: Мне непонятно назначение вашей ссылки про подключение jquery в вордпресс, если речь идёт о javascript-функциях. А также упоминание версий младше третьей, если речь идёт о WP 3.6

Comment: http://mywpnote.ru/poleznyie-sovetyi/wordpress-vstavka-javascript-v-zapis-ili-stranitsu/ Не дело это в тело вставлять:"Однако есть в них одна крайне неприятная особенность: в целях безопасности они перекодируют кавычки «» и другие используемые в скриптах знаки в специальные html-символы, что приводит к неработоспособности вставляемых java-скриптов.". Собственно, как и большинство движков. Любая работа со строкам потерпит фиаско.

Comment: У меня нет желания продолжать эту бессмысленную дискуссию. Огромное количество людей без проблем вставляют в редакторы поста WP js-коды, генерируемые фейсбуком и инстаграмом, для перепоста записей соцсети к себе в блог, не подозревая о том, что это невозможно. Иногда достаточно просто не придумывать себе дополнительных проблем

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B8

Comment: Во вторых насколько мне известно вставка facebook вставляется в заголовок, а потом в тело. Так что если вы допустим вставите все в тело у вас ничего не будет работать из-за кавычек. Но большинство людей ставит в виджет. А он как раз все поддерживает. Так что тут мне кажется вы вводите людей в заблуждение.

Comment: Пожалейте моё время, позвольте автору вопроса самому решить, заработает у него скрипт или сломается "из-за кавычек". Буду вам очень признательна

Answer (score 2):

В function.php добавляем следующий код:

```
//Настройка определенного css и js с помощью доп. полей.
function customscript_shortcode($atts, $text) {
   global $post;
   return get_post_meta($post->ID, $text, true);
}
@add_shortcode('customscript','customscript_shortcode');
//Настройка определенного css и js с помощью доп. полей.
```

Затем в самом посте/странице/кастом_посте в дополнительных полях называем поле например `js` и в правой части пишем сам скрипт облаченный в `<script>тут код</script>`. Все!  Таким же образом для поста можно и свой `css` установить. Забыл добавить, что установить его в пост в любом месте можно с помощью короткого кода: `[js]` или `[css]` соответственно.

Comment: Да, но тут существенный недостаток, например если там уже есть JQuery и мы запихнем другой в тело. Во вторых автор вопроса не указал пост у него или страница.

Comment: У меня стандартный скрипт работает. Я не думаю, что для поста может понадобится скрипт с использованием JQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Если говорить об удобном с точки зрения пользователя, то проще создать дубликат страницы, если у вас страница со скриптом. 
Если у вас пост, то дубликат контента и добавить в него скрипт(Лучше пере бдеть).
Если у вас в команде в основном разработки,то проще добавить произвольное поле.Но однако вас достанет ваш контент-менеджер в последствии.
Делаться это следующим образом:

```
<?php echo (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sample_name', true)); ?>
```

Вставляете ваш скрипт в footer(Для оптимизации) в поле в конкретном посте.